# Display Custom Fields in a SharePoint 2010 Content Query Web Part

Tags: development, content-query-web-part, ootb

[image]Using SharePoint 2010, Having Custom List With 4 Columns, Now I am Using Content Query Web-part To Display List Data ,But Currently It Display Only First Column,
SO How to Display Custom Fields in a SharePoint 2010 Content By Query Web Part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Open ItemStyle.xsl

2)Add Template just like DisplayTemplate And give Proper Name(Currently given Name='MyFirst')

3)Add Variable After name="DisplayTitle"/> Currently i have two Columns MobileNo And Address

4)At The End of Code Add span

select="$MobileNo"

select="$Address"

5)Save ItemStyle.xsl and Checkin

6)Click on Edit WebPart ->Presentation->Fields to display:
  Here u can See Your Custom Column MobileNo & Address

Enter internal Name Of Column MobileNo inside MobileNo Custom Columns  &
 Enter internal Name Of Column Address inside Address Custom Columns.

7)Click Ok

8)Done,now u can see all Custom Columns Data

u can see Total Code Below.(xsl:template name="MyFirst")

```
    <xsl:variable name="MobileNo"><xsl:value-of select="@MobileNo"></xsl:value-of></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="Address"><xsl:value-of select="@Address"></xsl:value-of></xsl:variable>

  <div class="item link-item">
    <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallPresenceStatusIconTemplate"/>
    <a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}" title="{@LinkToolTip}">
      <xsl:if test="$ItemsHaveStreams = 'True'">
        <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
          <xsl:value-of select="@OnClickForWebRendering"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="$ItemsHaveStreams != 'True' and @OpenInNewWindow = 'True'">
        <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
          <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$OnClickTargetAttribute"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="$DisplayTitle"/>
    </a> - <span><xsl:value-of select="$MobileNo"></xsl:value-of></span>
    <span><xsl:value-of select="$Address"></xsl:value-of></span>

  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

*A Content By Query Web Part displays a dynamic view of content on a page*

- The Web Part has two major aspects: query and presentation.  Query
  determines what content you want to show and presentation determines
  how you want to style and present the content.

*The Content By Query Web Part uses XSL style sheets to render these columns by default.*

- If you want to query for custom content types and render specific
  columns from those content types in the Web Part, you must perform
  some minor customization in the .webpart file.
- Edit the properties in the Web Part file to display custom fields. To
  access the .webpart file for the Web Part, on the Web Part's Edit
  menu, click Export.
- In the .webpart file, locate the CommonViewFields property. Use this
  property to specify the additional fields that you want to display in
  the Web Part. Add the internal names of the columns and the type.

  property name="CommonViewFields"
     type="string">KB_x0020_Title,Text;Product;
- This markup requests the Product column, to make the data in the columns available for
  rendering
- Export the database to use it in your SharePoint

  -To change the presentation for given column you have to make changes in .xsl file

Comment: Hey Amit, m Not Understand the .Xsl Part, Image not Display Properly On Above Link, U Have Any Other Link Or Explain That Part To Me.

Comment: I have updated my answer .Please let me know if your query is resolved

Comment: Amit, Currently m Edit The Property in exported File <property name="CommonViewFields" type="string">InternalColumnNameGoesHere, FieldType</property> THen Upload Again In WebPArt, THen After That Download The ItemStyle.Xsl Then Add Some Line In It Above the </xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: <xsl:template name="CustomStyle" match="Row[@Style='VendorCustomStyle']" mode="itemstyle">
    <html>
    <table width="100%">
    <xsl:if test="count(preceding-sibling::*)=0">
        <tr>
        <td width="8%" valign="top"><div class="item"><b>Name </b></div></td>
       
       
       </tr>
    </xsl:if>
    <tr>
       
        <td width="12%" valign="top"><div class="item"><xsl:value-of select="@Title" /></div></td>
        
               
    </tr>
    </table>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

Comment: After that Save the file, go to the Style Library folder and upload the updated file to XSL Style Sheets folder and click on save button. Now right click the ItemStyle file and publish a Major Version.

Comment: But It Shows Error On Web-part  Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.


Correlation ID:5643bcb3-eae1-4d48-af83-7adf0176ab73

Comment: Do not change Item style .xsl for now.Just import the webpart ,make changes into Common View Fields and import again.Then check whether web-part is displaying any error

Comment: ok But Still It Shows Error On Web Part , added  below line in webPart                                                      <property name="CommonViewFields" type="string" >Title,Text;DOB,DateTime;Dept,Choice;City,Choice</property>

Comment: Did you removed the style which you added in .xsl.It should be causing the error.Also the  list names should be internal name.http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/756834/Customizing-the-Content-Query-Web-Part-and-Item-St

Comment: ok now it Display Item,But  Only From First Column, renaming 3 Column Data Not Display.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21218/discussion-between-axay-and-amit-kotha).